# Adding items to a JList from ArrayList using DefaultListModel

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, jlist, defaultlistmodel

I'm trying to add items that are in an `ArrayList` to a `JList` which is working when I use the following code:

```
private void UpdateJList(){
    DefaultListModel<String> model = new DefaultListModel<String>();
    for(Person p : personList){
        model.addElement(p.ToString());
    }
    clientJList.setModel(model);
    clientJList.setSelectedIndex(0);
}
```

However, If I declare the `DefaultListModel` outside of the method, the adding increments each item, IE instead of adding one of each item, it adds multiple items. I was just wondering why this happens?

Comment: You must be executing UpdateJList() code twice, so the items get added twice. Post your [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org) that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: is that on repetitive calling of UpdateJList or just one call? may be worth putting a log in the method to ensure it gets called only once. I guess, you may want to do a .clear() on the model at the start of the model given that you are using it as a class level var.

Comment: @aishwarya - Thank you sir :)  clearing the model fixed the problem :)

Comment: please learn java naming conventions and stick to them

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you define `DefaultListModel` outside your update method then it becomes *Instance variable* so it will be having same value for one instance. Thus if you call this method over and over from same instance it will simply add more values to the existing list. Thus it shows multiple items.

**NOTE** : declaring `DefaultListModel` outside function does not cause any problem, making its object outside function is the problem. You can do the following without any problem :

```
DefaultListModel<String> model;

private void UpdateJList(){
    model = new DefaultListModel<String>();
    for(Person p : personList){
         model.addElement(p.ToString());
    }    
    clientJList.setModel(model);     
    clientJList.setSelectedIndex(0);
}
```

or you can try clearing the previous values from your model and then adding new values.